# FragmentPagerAdapter Swipe to show ListView 1/3 Screen Width

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, google-play, fragmentpageradapter

**EDIT:** [See my answer below-->](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998095/742030)

I am wanting to have a view that when swiped to the right, the listView is shown. Very much similar to what is implemented in the new Google Play Store (Sample image below). I think its a ViewPager but I tried duplicating it without prevail. I was thinking it may just be that the 'listView Page' width attribute was set to a specific dp but that doesn't work. I also tried modifying [pakerfeldt's viewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) and cant figure out how Google does this

Am I on the right track? If someone has an idea how to duplicate this, I would greatly appreciate it.  I think this may become a popular new way of showing a navigation view on tablets....? Code would be best of help.  Thank you!!

[image]

Swipe right:

[image]

Finnished swipe; the layout shows the list and **PART OF THE SECOND FRAGMENT (EXACTLY AS SHOWN)** The list fragment does not fill the screen:

[image]

When the user swipes left, the main page is only shown and if the user swipes left again the viewPager continues to the next page.

Comment: Just a SlidingDrawer? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: @Blundell Not even - See the New Market - AKA "Play Store". Thnx

Comment: When I was working with the Fragment Pager, I seem to remember google's code making an assumption that all screens would be the same size. I think an alternative way to approach this would be to consider the list fragment (0 above) and the pages (1 & 2 above) to be separate displayable elements. When the view pager is at the first element (1) and receives a swipe left gesture, use a fragment transition to modify the view layout to be like your final image. This should be possible by setting up gesture facilities in the parent activity.

Comment: @Nick Campion  [SEE MY ANSWER HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10998095/742030) This is what I am using and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late update. I implemented [this from walkingice on Gethub](https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar) with very little modification. Just use a conditional statement for a GestureDetector to swipe it into view only when a ViewPager id of '0' is in view.  I also added a toggle whithin my ActionBar

Comment: yeah it works... bit it works only with single different width fragment :/

Comment: @skyma not sure what you meen?? Its totally customizable.

Comment: I've no time to run the code, but it looks that I can have only one "Page" with different width and anything like ViewPager (view with Adapter) can be used :/

Comment: @skyman You can have as many pages as you like -layed out any way you like.  [Here is a functioning example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&hl=en)

Comment: ok... but how can I have multiple "not-full-width" pages (aka sidebars)?

Comment: @Andaero Where did you add that condition?

Answer (score 20):

The following code achieves the desired effect:

In `PageAdapter` :

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
if (position == 0) {
    return(0.5f);
} else {
    return (1.0f);       
}
```

Comment: Great! There can't be a simple method than this :)

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question one last time... make sure you also set up specific layouts for each size device.  In your screenshots it looks like your trying to run this on a tablet.  Are you getting the same results on a phone?

**Setting up your Layout**

Make sure your layout is simular to this and has the ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/body_background">

<include layout="@layout/pagerbar" />
<include layout="@layout/colorstrip" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/example_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Setting up your Activity**

Setup your PagerAdapter in your "FragmentActivity" and make sure you implement   "OnPageChangeListener".  Then properly setup your PagerAdapter in your onCreate.

```
public class Activity extends FragmentActivity 
             implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener { 
   ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.example_pager);

       pager.setAdapter(adapter);
       pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
       pager.setCurrentItem(MyFragment.PAGE_LEFT);

       ...
   }


   /* setup your PagerAdapter which extends FragmentPagerAdapter */

   static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       public static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

       private MyFragment[] mFragments = new MyFragment[NUM_PAGES];

          public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
           super(fragmentManager);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return NUM_PAGES;
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           if (mFragments[position] == null) {
               /* this calls the newInstance from when you setup the ListFragment */
               mFragments[position] = MyFragment.newInstance(position);
           }

           return mFragments[position];
       }
   }

 ...
```

**Setting up your Fragment**

When you setup your actual ListFragment (your listViews) you can create multiple instances with arguments like the following:

```
  public static final int PAGE_LEFT = 0;
  public static final int PAGE_RIGHT = 1;

  static MyFragment newInstance(int num) {
       MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt("num", num);

       fragment.setArguments(args);
       return fragment;
   }
```

When you reload the listViews (how ever you decide to implement this) you can figure out which fragment instance you are on using the arguments like so:

```
    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
```

If you step through your code you will notice that it will step through each instance so the above code is only needed in your **onCreate** and a reload method may look like this:

```
private void reloadFromArguments() {
    /* mNum is a variable which was created for each instance in the onCreate */
    switch (mNum) {
        case PAGE_LEFT:
            /* maybe a query here would fit your needs? */
            break;

        case PAGE_RIGHT:
            /* maybe a query here would fit your needs? */
            break;
    }
}
```

Few Sources that may help you out with examples that you could build from rather then starting from scratch:

More explanation and example from playground.
http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html
   which is references to:
   http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/

More info and some good linkage.
http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2012/03/16/responsive-mobile-design-on-android-from-view-pager-to-action-bar-tabs.html

If you have more specific questions post and I can always Edit (update) my answer to address your questions.  Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

[ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) is a part of the [Compatibly Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

If you're using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), then you can use `ViewPager` to swipe between them.

[Here's an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html) of combining `Fragments` and `ViewPager`

In your particular case, you would want to create a `ListFragment` and then implement `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thnx but that is what Iv'e been playing with too. I cant figure how to have fragment 0 (or the first page) not occupy the entire screen. Please see the Play Store app.

Comment: If you're having layout problems, then adjust your layout. You have to inflate one for your `Fragment`.

Comment: Ah, wait. I think what you're talking about is the margin between `Fragments`. If that's the case, then use `setPageMargin()` with `ViewPager` to create space between each `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to implement a "side navigation" beside a standard [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

I've read 2 different articles on this pattern:

The first one on the pattern itself:

[Android Ui Pattern Emerging UI Pattern - Side Navigation](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html)

The second on a more detailed way of who to build it:

Cyril Mottier Fly-in app menu [#1](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658) [#2](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=701) [#3](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=717)

This second article is referenced in Android Ui Pattern blog.

Answer (score 0):

With a little Trick, the behavior can be achieved with the ScrollView-Behavior inside the ViewPager. If you only want to restrict the area of the most left fragment, you can restrict the scroll limits of the ScrollView.

In your case:
in the onPageChangeListener of the ViewPager do something like that:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    restrictLeftScroll();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    restrictLeftScroll();
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

}

private void restrictLeftScroll() {

    if (display != null) {

        /* get display size */
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        /* get desired Width of left fragment */
        int fragmentWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.category_fragment_width);

        if (mViewPager.getScrollX() < size.x - fragmentWidth) {
            mViewPager.scrollTo(size.x - fragmentWidth, mViewPager.getScrollY());
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code worked for me without problems. ;)

Comment: It worked for me without problems. I got the same result as in the play-store. It only works for the most left fragment. In the onPageScroll events, you can steer the behaviour of the extended ViewPager. Use my `restrictLeftScroll()` function to get the same as in the play store.