# how to show other application inside my main xml?

Tags: android

how i will show other activity inside my activity any idea how i will do that?
but i want to show other activity inside my main layout and take 50% of screen not show on full screen what will i do any idea???

```
String packageName = "com.mobile_banking"; // you must know package name
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Activity, you can't show 2 Activities in single one.

What you are looking for is a **FragmentActivity** and **Fragments** with custom sizes in it.

First learn about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Once you learn the basics, you can follow these links:

[Android Two Fragments in Same Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580593/android-two-fragments-in-same-activity)

[How to implement two fragments in single view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400699/how-to-implement-two-fragments-in-single-view)

Comment: not two activity i want to divide my main xml in 2 parts freist part show same application ui second part show another application(which is google navigation)

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
   Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + destination));
   startActivity(i);

Comment: im using this google.navigation app but when launch this  app original app not show on screen how i iwll restrick other app to show only limited area of screen