# How to focus viewHolder of recycler view in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want when the user scrolls horizontally in the recycler view the view holder of recycler view zoom a little bit like this. Like the first recycler view of the below picture.Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you can do this much easier with `ViewPager2`

Comment: I would recommend implementing the top `RecyclerView` with a `ViewPager`. You can have the desired behavior following the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693836/fragmentpageradapter-swipe-to-show-listview-1-3-screen-width

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily created by android `ViewPager2` follow this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8192680-viewpager2-in-android-getting-started) and use `scale` effect to zoom your selected view a little bit. [Here](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2) is android's official sample project of `ViewPager2`, this will help you much too.